# R ggplot2: changing the legend title and labels in this example dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
n   value   name
1   20  1
2   30  1
3   25  1
1   40  2
2   12  2
3   39  2
```

This is how I plot it now:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("test", sep = "\t", header = TRUE,)
ggplot(data, aes(n, value,color=as.character(name))) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value))
dev.off()
```

[image]
I would like to change "as.character(name)" to "New Title" and the values "1" and "2" to "value1" and "value2".

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("test", sep = "\t", header = TRUE,)
ggplot(data, aes(n, value,color=as.character(name))) + geom_point(aes(n,value)) 
+ geom_line(aes(n,value)) +
 scale_fill_manual(name="My title", values=c("value1", "value2"))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `scale_color_manual` not `scale_fill_manual`. Then `values` refers to color values, which you must supply, and the third parameter is `labels`.

```
+ scale_color_manual(name = "New Title", 
                     labels = c("value1", "value2"), 
                     values = c("red", "green"))
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was wondering is it possible to pass the same colors as you would otherwise have with `color = as.character(p)`?

Comment: Yes, you can supply the values for those colors, but the easier way is to use instead `scale_color_discrete` and omit the `values` parameter.